# Visual Studio 2012: How to remove an delete project project from the source-control-explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I deleted a TFS project based on [this articel](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2013/09/13/how-to-delete-a-team-project-from-team-foundation-service.aspx) and it is gone, but inside my Visual Studio 2012, in the "Source Control Explorer" view the project is still listed.

How do I remove the project in the Source Control Explorer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, solved. All what was missing is "Undo pending changes" at project-level. After this operation the project is gone :)